# Using row_number with prepare statements

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I'm making a table which has 30 entries in in, from a table from MySQL. I'm using `LIMIT 30` in the code sent to sql, but there's also a bunch of next pages. The table would have last name, first name and an id. At the bottom of the page, there's a next page button. It links to the same page but sends the last id in a get variable.

```
<a href=<?php echo "students_view.php?id=$lastvari"; ?>><button type="button">Next Page</button></a>
```

$lastvari being the last id. When calling the data from mysql, I'm using prepare statements:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT Last_Name, First_Name, Student_ID FROM Students LIMIT 30");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($last_name, $first_name, $student_id);
```

How would I tell MySQL to start after the ID that was sent to it? I research row_number() but I'm not sure if that's what I'm looking for. Thanks all :)

Answer (score 0):

To get the second page, use [the two-number form of `LIMIT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html#idp56908288):

```
SELECT Last_Name, First_Name, Student_ID FROM Students LIMIT 30,30
```

To get the third page:

```
SELECT Last_Name, First_Name, Student_ID FROM Students LIMIT 60,30
```

and so on. The first page would be `LIMIT 0,30`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing Last id each and everytime to next page I would suggest an alternative.
Assume current url is www.yoursite/students_view.php?page=0

```
<?php
$start = $_GET['page'] * 30;
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT Last_Name, First_Name, Student_ID FROM Students LIMIT $start, 30");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($last_name, $first_name, $student_id);
?>

<?php
$page = $_GET['page']; //don't forget to sanitize
$page = $page+1;
?>
<a href="<?php echo "students_view.php?page=$page"; ?>" >
   <button type="button">Next Page</button>
</a>
```